# Dask Distributed - Recommended package versions

Tags: dask, dask-distributed, dask-delayed

I recently tried upgrading my Dask Distributed to 2.3.0 and fastparquet to 0.3.2, but found that it was leading to deadlocks and worker dropouts on code that works with Dask Distributed 2.1.0 (I want to make use of the read_parquet feature 'gather_statistics=False', which is in Dask 2.2.0+).  It looks like  tornado may not be playing nice with the newer versions of Dask - I get errors like what I pasted at the bottom.

Upgrading tornado does not appear to solve the stability issues I'm encountering with Dask 2.3.0.  The current set of relevant packages in my cluster, which appears to be stable, is:

```
Python 3.7.3

dask==2.1.0 

distributed==2.1.0 

tornado==6.0.2

blosc==1.8.1 

bokeh==1.2.0 

cloudpickle==1.2.1 

fastparquet==0.3.1 

fsspec==0.4.1 

msgpack==0.6.1 

numpy==1.16.1 

pandas==0.24.2 

six==1.12.0 

toolz==0.9.0 

colorama==0.4.1 

numba==0.44.1 

python-snappy==0.5.1 

Cython==0.29.13

Nodes are a mix of Ubuntu 18 and 19
```

What is the recommended set of package versions that should be stable with Dask Distributed 2.3.x?

Are there any other packages I should ensure all nodes in my cluster have the same version of?

```
2019-09-10 01:25:17,211 - INFO - 192.168.0.152 - tornado.application - ERROR - Exception in callback functools.partial(<bound method IOLoop._discard_future_result of <tornado.platform.asyncio.AsyncIOLoop object at 0x7f8d8963af28>>, <Future finished exception=TypeError("'NoneType' object is not subscriptable")>)

2019-09-10 01:25:17,214 - INFO - 192.168.0.152 - Traceback (most recent call last):

2019-09-10 01:25:17,265 - INFO - 192.168.0.152 -   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 743, in _run_callback

2019-09-10 01:25:17,300 - INFO - 192.168.0.152 -     ret = callback()

2019-09-10 01:25:17,308 - INFO - 192.168.0.152 -   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 767, in _discard_future_result

2019-09-10 01:25:17,344 - INFO - 192.168.0.152 -     future.result()

2019-09-10 01:25:17,373 - INFO - 192.168.0.152 -   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 742, in run

2019-09-10 01:25:17,379 - INFO - 192.168.0.152 -     yielded = self.gen.send(value)

2019-09-10 01:25:17,394 - INFO - 192.168.0.152 -   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/distributed/worker.py", line 796, in heartbeat

2019-09-10 01:25:17,411 - INFO - 192.168.0.152 -     if response["status"] == "missing":

2019-09-10 01:25:17,447 - INFO - 192.168.0.152 - TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Have you considered opening an issue on [github](https://github.com/dask/dask)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We co-test and co-release Dask's related sub-packages.  We endeavor to make it so that at any time, the most recent releases of all packages is in a good working state.

We may fail at this from time to time, but if we do, then it is a bug.  In these cases I recommend raising a bug report on Github.